# Linear autonomous systems in the plane: When do phase curves rotate clockwise?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For a linear autonomous system in the plane
$$ \mathbf{\dot{x}} = \begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ c & d \end{pmatrix}\mathbf{x} \qquad (a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R})$$
with determinant $D = ad - bc$ and trace $T = a + d$ we have the characteristic polynomial
$$ \chi(\lambda) = \lambda^2 - T\lambda + D$$
and the eigenvalues
$$ \lambda_{1, 2} = \frac{T \pm \sqrt{\Delta}}{2}, \qquad \Delta = T^2 - 4D $$
We know that the phase curves will rotate around the origin iff $\Delta < 0$.

**Question:** How can one determine **using $a, b, c, d$**, whether the phase curves turn clockwise or counter-clockwise?

**Counterexample:** The System
$$ \mathbf{\dot{x}} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & s\\ -s & 1 \end{pmatrix}\mathbf{x} \qquad (s \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \})$$
will rotate clockwise for $s > 0$ and counter-clockwise for $s<0$, but in *both cases* we have
$$ D = 1 + s^2 > 0, \qquad T = 2, \qquad \Delta = -4s^2 < 0 $$
so these quantities will **not** suffice to determine the orientation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspired by [amd](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/265466/amd)'s help I *did the math*:

The original system
$$ \mathbf{\dot{x}} = \begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ c & d \end{pmatrix}\mathbf{x}, \qquad D = ad - bc, \qquad T = a + d $$
has the eigenvalues
$$ \lambda_{\pm} = \frac{T \pm i\sqrt{|\Delta|}}{2}, \qquad |\Delta| = 4D - T^2 > 0 $$
with corresponding eigenvectors
$$ v_{\pm} = \begin{pmatrix} -a+d \mp i\sqrt{|\Delta|}\\ -2c \end{pmatrix} $$

We want to relate it to the system
$$ \mathbf{\dot{w}} = \begin{pmatrix} \alpha & -\beta\\ \beta & \alpha \end{pmatrix}\mathbf{w}, \qquad \alpha = \Re\left(\lambda_{+}\right) = \frac{T}{2}, \qquad \beta = \Im\left(\lambda_{+}\right) = \frac{\sqrt{|\Delta|}}{2} > 0 $$
which is spinning counter-clockwise because of $\beta > 0$ (as pointed out by [amd](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/265466/amd)) and has the *same eigenvalues*, but now with the corresponding eigenvectors
$$ w_{\pm} = \begin{pmatrix} \pm i\\ 1 \end{pmatrix} $$

We are looking for a Matrix $B$ such that
$$ \begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ c & d \end{pmatrix} = B\begin{pmatrix} \alpha & -\beta\\ \beta & \alpha \end{pmatrix}B^{-1}, \qquad \mathbf{x} = B\mathbf{w} $$
Such a matrix is uniquely defined by the condition
$$ (v_{+} \mid v_{-} ) = B(w_{+} \mid w_{-} ) = B\begin{pmatrix} i & -i\\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix} $$
and hence computes to
$$ B = \begin{pmatrix} -a+d - i\sqrt{|\Delta|} & -a+d + i\sqrt{|\Delta|}\\ -2c & -2c \end{pmatrix} \frac{1}{2i} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & i\\ -1 & i \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -\sqrt{|\Delta|} & d - a\\ 0 & -2c\end{pmatrix} $$
with determinant $\det B = 2c\sqrt{|\Delta|}$ yielding the result

> - $c > 0$: The matrix $B$ preserves orientation as $\det B > 0$, hence $\mathbf{x} = B\mathbf{w}$ rotates **counter-clockwise** just like $\mathbb{w}$.
> - $c < 0$: The matrix $B$ inverts orientation as $\det B < 0$, hence $\mathbf{x} = B\mathbf{w}$ rotates **clockwise**.
> - $c = 0$: Leads to real eigenvalues $a$ and $d$, so the system does **not rotate**.

Should you be surprised that the orientation only depends on $c$, then please note: If
$$ B = \begin{pmatrix} e & f\\ g & h \end{pmatrix} \in GL(2,\mathbb{R}) $$
is an invertible real matrix, then we have $g \neq 0$ or $h \neq 0$ and
$$ B\begin{pmatrix} \alpha & -\beta\\ \beta & \alpha \end{pmatrix}B^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} ? & -\beta\frac{e^2 + f^2}{\det B}\\ \beta\frac{g^2 + h^2}{\det B} & ? \end{pmatrix} $$
and since $g^2 + h^2 >0$ the sign of the "lower left coefficient" only changes if $\det B < 0$.

Comment: Nice work! Another way to reach this conclusion is to set $G=A-\alpha I$, where $A$ is our original matrix. Cayley-Hamilton tells us that $(A-\alpha I)^2=G^2=-\beta^2 I$. So, for $B$ we can choose any convenient vector $\mathbf v_1$ as its first column, and its second column will be $\beta^{-1}G\mathbf v_1$. Taking $\mathbf v_1=\langle 1,0\rangle$ gives $\operatorname{Det}B=c/\beta$.

Comment: Note that the matrix $B$ is not unique. For instance, for any scalar $c\ne 0$, $(cB)M(cB)^{-1}=BMB^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

You answered your question yourself, but here is somewhat easier answer.

First note that to have the origin with complex eigenvalues if is necessary to have $b,c\neq 0$ and $bc<0$. Moreover $(a-d)^2+4bc<0$.

Now consider the expression
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\arctan\frac{x_2(t)}{x_1(t)}=\frac{\dot x_2 x_1-\dot x_1x_2}{x_1^2+x_2^2}=\frac{cx_1^2+(d-a)x_1x_2-bx_2^2}{x_1^2+x_2^2}\,.
$$
Assuming that $b>0$ or (equivalently, $c<0$), one should show that the numerator is a negative definite form, which means that
$$
\dot \theta(t)<0,
$$
or that the rotation is clockwise. Similarly for the case $b<0,c>0$, which, of course, coincides with your work.

Answer (score 1):

In short, you’ve more or less answered your own question: it depends on the sign of $s$.

If the matrix of the equation is of the form $\pmatrix{\alpha&-\beta\\ \beta&\alpha}$, with $\beta$ positive, the phase curves are counterclockwise spirals with the direction of motion dependent on $\alpha$: When $\alpha>0$, the point moves outward as $t\to\infty$; when $\alpha<0$, the point moves inward instead.

In your specific example, when $s<0$, the solution is $$e^t\pmatrix{\cos\beta t&-\sin\beta t\\ \sin\beta t&\cos\beta t},$$ where $\beta=-s>0$. When $s>0$, this is the same as replacing $\beta$ with $-\beta$ in the solution, which will clearly spiral clockwise as a result.

Another way to look at the $s>0$ case is to rewrite the matrix in the differential equation as $$\pmatrix{-1&0\\0&1}\pmatrix{1&-s\\ s&1}\pmatrix{-1&0\\0&1}^{-1}.
$$ This transformation flips the $x$-axis, turning the counterclockwise spiral into a clockwise one.

Comment: The general case, with complete eigenvalues $\alpha\pm i\beta$ $(\beta>0)$, isn’t any different. The matrix of the equation will be of the form $A=B\pmatrix{\alpha&-\beta\\ \beta&\alpha}B^{-1}$. If $B$ is orientation-preserving (i.e., $\operatorname{Det} B>0$), then you have a counterclockwise spiral with the point moving outward or inward depending on the sign of $\alpha$. If $\operatorname{Det} B<0$, you have a clockwise spiral. If you have real eigenvalues, you don’t get a spiral, but you can still determine a “direction” with their signs.

Comment: Using your hints I posted the full calculation of $\det B$ with the rather surprising result that it depends upon the sign of $c$. Would you mind checking my argumentation?