# Fixed points of nonlinear systems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

For nonlinear systems, I know the phase portrait at a fixed point is a spiral when the eigenvalues are complex conjugates with real parts, and centre when they have no real parts. But how should I determine if it's "left-handed" or "right-handed" spiral, or which way the centre is turning?

Comment: You might find [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1478460/265466) relevant.

Comment: Perhaps one should add that in general the statement "the phase portrait at a fixed point is a [...] center when they have no real parts" is false.

Answer (score 1):

Find the direction of the velocity vector $d{\bf x}/dt$ at some point away from the origin in the linearized system.  See e.g. [these notes](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~israel/m215/linphase/linphase.html) and [these](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~israel/m215/nonlin/nonlin.html).